# PHP, Mysql query different tables in one function

Tags: php, mysql

```
function getDepartmentAndCondition($dep, $userid, $cond) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM department WHERE ID='$dep'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $DepConInfo['Department'] = $row['Department'];
    }
    $userName = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE FacebookID = '$userid'") or die ("<hr>error in SQL query: " . mysql_error() . "<hr>");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($username)) {
        $DepConInfo['Name'] = $row['name'];

    }

    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM condition WHERE ID= '$cond' ")
    or die("<hr>error in SQL query: " . mysql_error() . "<hr>");
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        $DepConInfo['Condition'] = $row2['Condition'];
    }


    return $DepConInfo;

}
```

`$dep`, `$userid`, and `$cond` are all `int`s. the first one `$DepConInfo['Department']` is returning the right string, but the other two fail with the error

> **Warning**: `mysql_fetch_array()`: supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in ...

---

ok I rewrote the function

```
 function getCondition($cond) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM condition WHERE ID = '$cond' "; 
    $sql = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$sql) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);    
}
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
       {
       $condition = $row2['Name'];
       }
    return $condition;
}
```

but I'm still getting an error:
`Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition WHERE id = '1'' at line 1 Whole query: SELECT * FROM condition WHERE ID = '1'`

the table "condition" has two columns "ID" and "Name".

Comment: are you sure you have the rows available for your condition in the table on database.

Answer (score 3):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($username)) {
```

PHP is case-sensitive: you have `$username` with wrong caps - should be `$userName`

Additionally, based on your naming convention in the first and third queries

```
$DepConInfo['Name'] = $row['name'];
```

is probably incorrect and should be capitalized as `$row['Name']`

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDepartment($dep) { 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM department WHERE ID = '$dep'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query); 
    if (!$result) { 
        echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $department = $row['Department'];
    }
    return $department;
}

function getName($userid) { 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE FacebookID = '$userid'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql); 
    if (!$result) { 
        echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $user_name = $row['Name'];
    }
    return $username;
}

function getCondition($cond) { 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM condition WHERE id = '$cond'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql); 
    if (!$result) { 
        echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $condition = $row['Condition'];
    }
    return $condition;
}

$department = getDepartment($dep);
$username = getName($userid);
$condition = getCondition($cond);
```

I'm writing this from my head so I did not test it, but it should work or at least get you on your way. If not let me know. Mind capitalization using caps in your dbase table and column names can make things more confusing. Use $sql to store your query, use $result to store the result. This is more descriptive. Good luck!

Comment: This is an inderect answer to your problem, but this style will also help you prevent and solve problems in the future.

Comment: ok so i rewrote the function
<code>function getCondition($cond) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM condition WHERE id = '$cond' "; 
    $sql = mysql_query($query);
    
    if (!$sql) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);    
}
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
       {
       $condition = $row2['Name'];
       }
    return $condition;
}</code>

Comment: There is a great book that I have read which teaches coding conventions and best practices. This helped me out a lot. It's called 'Clean Code' and it's a must read for every coder. [Clean Code on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882)